# Quantity of motion from quaternions

Tags: quaternions

I made some recordings from a head tracker which provides the 4 values of the quaternions, which are saved in a csv (each row is a set of quaternion plus a timestamp).
I need to calculate for the whole recording how much the head moved. This is needed for an experiment where I would like to see whether under a condition the head moved more or less compared to another condition.

What is the best way to get a single quantity for each recording?
I have some proposals but I do not know how much appropriate they are:

PROPOSAL 1) I calculate the cumulative sum of the absolute value of the derivatives for each quaternion value, then I sum the 4 sums together to get a single value

PROPOSAL 2) I calculate the cumulative sum of the absolute value of the derivatives of the norm

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just want a rough estimate of total angular movement as a single value. One way is to assume minimum rotation angle between quaternion samples and then just add up those angles. E.g., suppose two consecutive quaternion samples are q1 and q2. Then calculate the quaternion multiply q = q1 * inv(q2) and your delta-angle for that step is 2*acos(abs(qw)). Do this for each step and add up all the delta angles.

Comment: yes exactly, I need a single value. Can you please tell me why the method of  calculating the cumulative sum of the absolute value of the derivatives of the norm is not correct? In your formula above it is not clear what qw is, could you please clarify?

Comment: Can you post the equations you use to calculate the "derivatives of the norm"? And how you think this is related to angular motion? Also, qw is the standard nomenclature used for the "scalar" element of q. The other three elements of q are typically known as the "vector" parts qx, qy, qz.

Comment: the norm is simply the square root of the values and the derivative is simply the subtraction of the norm a time t and the norm at time t - 1.  Is my method wrong? If so, why?

Comment: This is still unclear to me. I really need to see the exact equations you are using, not a wordy description of them. For instance, the "norm at time t" of what? If it is the norm of the quaternion at time t, and the quaternion is a valid rotation quaternion, then the norm will be 1 and subtracting it from the next norm is simply going to result in 1-1=0. Which of course makes no sense. So please post the exact equations you would be using for this "derivatives of the norm" scheme for two consecutive quaternions q1 and q2.

Comment: The norm of a quaternion is defined by |q|=√q24+q21+q22+q23. So what I did to calculate the derivative is simpli a subtraction: for quaternion q1 at time t1, and quaternion q2 at time t2, the derivative at t2 is |q2| - |q1|. This makes sense. If q1 and q2 have the same coefficients, then the norm is identical and the derivative will be 0.

Comment: Still confused here. What you have shown for the "norm" is *not* the definition of the norm of a quaternion. I don't know what it is or what it could be used for. In fact, if the quaternion elements happen to be negative you could wind up with the square root of a negative number. Is that equation what you meant to type or is it a typo?

Comment: Sorry, of course this is a typo. I am using the conventional definition of a norm of a quaternion, the square root so the four coefficients need to be a power of 2, the formatting did not help…

Comment: OK, so you really did mean the convention norm of the quaternion. Then let's focus on the next question which I pointed out earlier. Why do you think |q2| and |q1| will be anything other than 1 if they are both valid rotation quaternions?

Comment: I don’t know how to answer the question because my knowledge of quaternions is limited. Why is my approach wrong? What do you suggest? Thanks